# Updating row mapping after external sorting

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid

I've been using ng-grid (2.0.7) in an AngularJS (1.2.0-rc2) project with an external search function. My external sort function is working so far, even the grid data gets updated.

Unfortunately, the rows are keeping their previous order. How can I tell the grid to update the row order? I don't want to mess around with ng-grid internals like rowMap and rowCache ...

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Could you shed some more light on what exactly you are doing with the external search and/or external sort? You probably just need to call $scope.gridOptions.sortBy('your-column-name');

Comment: Your hint doesn't work :(

Comment: My grid should display customer data. Several rows belong to one customer. A thick line should separate rows belonging to different customers - only the last grid row won't have such a line. I handle this by using a customized row template and adding a special property to each row item. If this is set the line will be visible.
Sorting the rows by the customer name changes the order of the row items - and I have to adapt the property which triggers the drawing of the bar. This works so far (I can see it in the grid) - but the grid doesn't update the row order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a bug in this version of ng-grid.

The following pull request solves this issue: https://github.com/wattsbn/ng-grid/commit/843938d30a157dfabda3f69116561c94f9177e6e

Answer (score 0):

Thank you ! This also fixed a problem I was seeing running into when unselected items after changing the sort and or filter. I needed to prevent more than 50 items from being selected after clicking the select all checkbox. Worked great until the sort or filter changed. After that the item indexes would get confused and I would have seemingly random selections and checkboxes. This fixed that problem for me.